# How do I authenticate to view mongodb's http console?

Tags: authentication, mongodb

I'm running a mongodb process with the following line:

/usr/bin/mongod --dbpath /var/db/mongo --journal

According to mongodb's docs: 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Http+Interface

I should be able to access the http console with http://myhost:28017

When I attempt to access the page it asks for authentication.

According to the docs if security is configured I would need to authenticate. But after looking at mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication it seems clear to me I'm not using any authentication. I don't run the process with the --auth option, nor are there any users when I run a db.system.users.find() command.

What's going on here?

Comment: What version of mongod are you running?  What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: I faced this in mongo 3... as after I create user, I can't pass authentication on web interface

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to reproduce this, and this is not the intended behavior.  I have filed https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4601  The fix version is 2.1.1

Thank you for bringing this to our attention!

In the meantime, there are two work-arounds:
1) Enter the credentials for authentication in the browser pop-up window
2) Remove all user credentials from each of your DBs (including admin) using db.system.users.remove()

Either of these should allow you to view the http console.

Comment: I went ahead and removed all user credentials from my DB, and that has fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Greetings Brain,
                i am using mongo V 2.4.6 and its on default port 27017, its http console is enabled by default but when you try to access from Network it ask for password and i dont know why as i am new to this and dont know the exact reason. by i have a way to access it.

Create a tunnel to your mongo Server and when you access, it wont ask for password. and if you are using putty.

1. enter host name
2. go to ssh on left menu options and click +
3. Than Click on tunnel
4. in Source port type 28017
5. in destination type localhost colon port 28017(sorry dont know how to write http url in localhost here in my post)
6. not click open and provide ssh username and password
7. now open browser on PC from where you are doing ssh .Type localhost and port 28017

and Boom its accessible and wont ask for username and password. hope it work for you, let me know if u need any help.